# How to close a formless C# application

Tags: .net

My application has no forms. It runs by calling Application.Run();

Comment: if it has no forms, why are you calling Application.Run? Shouldn't it be a console app or a windows service instead?

Comment: He might need to process user events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option is `Environment.Exit()`, however if your application does rely on the Application classes, `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()` is the more "proper" way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the MSDN documentation for the [Application.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) suggests:

- [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit.aspx)
- [Application.ExitThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exitthread.aspx)

*Note, that most Windows Forms developers will not need to use Application.Run(). Are you sure you need message pumping in your app?*