# How to stop program executing further in C#

Tags: c#

```
string FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            if (FirstName.Length > 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(".......................................");
            }
            if(FirstName.Length<3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("....................");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("...................");
            string SecondName = Console.ReadLine();
            if (SecondName.Length > 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(".............................");
            }
            if(SecondName.Length<3)
            {
```

I want to stop the program if they press enter without putting a value,how to do it??/?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close a formless C# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181018/how-to-close-a-formless-c-sharp-application)

Comment: This question and your other question indicates you are completely new to C#. Please read some tutorials first.

Comment: Read more answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4898117/468718

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to have a non empty string value as an input from console and if input is empty then want to terminate your application. Use following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a value: ");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
//If pressed enter here without a  value or data, how to stop the  program here without
//further execution??
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
  return;
else
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("you have entered: '{0}'", str));
  Console.Read();
}
```

If user will enter any kind of empty string or white spaces, the application will be terminated the moment he/she will press enter.

Answer (score 15):

```
string key = Console.ReadKey().ToString();  //Read what is being pressed
if(key == "") {
    Console.WriteLine("User pressed enter!");
    return; //stop further execution
}
```

Comment: I mean If  "enter" is pressed without any value,
what if they press enter after putting a value

Comment: I mean to say  only if "enter" is pressed without any value,what if they put a value and press enter????

Comment: @user2996625 If you add some value, the above if statement won't get executed.  Do you want to stop even if you enter some values?

Answer (score 5):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. If nothing is typed and the human just presses the enter key, we'll get an empty string.

There are a number of ways to test whether a string is "empty" for various definitions of empty. Some common definitions of empty and how to test for them:

- non-`null` and containing no data: `myString.Length == 0`
- `null` or containing no data: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)`
- `null`, empty, or just whitespace: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)`

[`Environment.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will end the process with the exit code you specify.

Combine one of the tests above with `Environment.Exit()` (and probably an `if`) and you can stop the process when there's no "value or data".

Also note, that returning from `Main` is another way to exit the process.